# SQL Cast quirkiness

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, sql-server-2014

I have always used CONVERT (and not CAST), as I assumed the former would recognize types and do an appropriate conversion where as the latter is simply trying to interpret a stream of bytes differently. But just learned that CAST=CONVERT for most purposes!

But can someone explain why the following happens. CAST produces different results for the same value (101), but represented differently - decimal (101) and hexadecimal (0x65) representations.

```
select cast(0x65 as varchar(5))
-----
e

select cast(101 as varchar(5))
-----
101
```

EDIT:
The query was run from SSMS.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: If you wanted the 101 to change into an 'e'? Then have a look at the [CHAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql) function.  The reverse of that is the [ASCII](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ascii-transact-sql) function.

Comment: The type of `0x65` is `VARBINARY(1)`. The type of `101` is `INT`. (You can find this out using `SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(0x65, 'BaseType')`.) The conversion rules for both types are different. (While `0x65 = 101`, this is only true because `VARBINARY(1)` implicitly converts to `INT`.)

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using SQL Server (where the confusion between the two functions would make sense).

That is simple.  `0x` defines a *binary constant*.  `101` is a numeric constant.  These are not the same thing.

When you convert a binary constant to a string, it attempts to interpret the constant as a character.  When you convert a number to a string, SQL Server converts the decimal representation.

You can learn more about constants in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to convert to completely different values. As Gordon mentioned, one is binary representation while the other is numeric.

But you need to note that there is some differences between `CAST` and `CONVERT`:

> 1. CAST is part of the ANSI-SQL specification; whereas, CONVERT is not.  In fact, CONVERT is Microsoft SQL Server implementation specific.
> 2. CONVERT differences lie in that it accepts an optional style
>      parameter which is used for formatting.

Read more here: https://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-the-difference-between-cast-and-convert/